# Two-criteria priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

Is there a not too complicated way how to implement a priority queue working with two criteria? The queue gets created with 2 `Comparator`s and provides (besides `add`) the operations `poll1()` and `poll2()`, where each removes and returns the smallest element according to the corresponding comparator.

Note that it has nothing in common with these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25232722/581205) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22733351/581205).

## Motivation

My use case is [Branch and Bound Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). Expanding the candidate with the best bound is provably optimal when you're given an unlimited time. Assuming an unlimited time is provably wrong.

Strictly following this strategy often ends up with having no solution at all when the deadline comes. A simple band-aid is to direct the search towards a solution first and then switch to the best bound strategy. This is rather unsatisfactory as the first solution found can be of an arbitrary low quality.

That's why I'd like to use the two criteria queue: In one step, expand the best bound candidate and in another, expand the "best looking" candidate according to some heuristics.

Another possible use would be for pareto-optimization.

Comment: Why not create a facade backed by two `PriorityQueue`s?

Comment: Agreed. The mechanics of a `PriorityQueue` rely on being able to compare to items.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How would you remove the element obtained by `poll1()` from the second queue?

Comment: Store it temporarily, call `remove(Object)` (passing it in) on the second `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Complexity? `O(n)`?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but should be less than `O(n)`. The removal isn't like `poll`, from the top. It can remove anywhere and still has to re-organize the underlying structure (probably a balanced heap/tree in most implementations).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `java.util.PriorityQueue` uses a heap rather than a tree as it's faster. With two `SortedSet`s it could work.

Comment: Two priority queues, a facade and a wrapper with a value indicating wheter item has been already consumed (if it has, then call poll again...)

Comment: @SamiKorhonen This sounds good, but it can keep too many elements in the queue too long. Maybe some periodic cleanup would solve it.

Comment: You could set reference from wrapper to actual object as null once you mark the object as used. I would not expect you to encounter any problems, even if you had few thousand invalid references in the queue

Comment: I guess you could have a counter of invalid references per queue. And if counter goes above specified threshold, you would just use iterator to remove them. You could use a ReadWrite lock to sync cleanups: use read lock for polling and write lock for cleanup. Atomics should work well as counters

Comment: @SamiKorhonen This nulling can't work in general, as the actual object is needed for sorting. You'd need to store the value used for sorting in the wrapper and I'm not sure if it's smaller than my actual object. ++ The counter idea sounds good.

Comment: Tru, you would need to cache weight in the wrapping element. Without knowing the actual data and use case, it's hard to say what would be an efficient implementation

Comment: Sounds somewhat interesting, but I'd be curious to see how this is intended to be used (particularly, a convincing example where this makes more sense than two separate priority queues)

Comment: @Marco13 Added a motivation paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object of this task would hopefully be to maintain the same amoritized runtimes for the goal priority queue.

These runtimes are `O(log n)` for insertion and removal.

Maintain two priority queues each with their own comparator. Maintain a map of the counts of the objects added. When an object is removed from the queue, decrement the count. If the object you attempt to poll from the queue has a count <= 0, then poll another item.

The following implementation maintains the runtimes. It has amoritized `O(log n)` for insertion and removal. Because each element is added to each queue and removed from each queue only once, it must be a constant multiple of the runtime of a single queue. In addition, the map has insertion and removal times of `O(1)`, which does not contribute to the `O(log n)` runtime for the queues.

```
public class DualPriorityQueue<T> {

    private Queue<T> queue1, queue2;
    private Map<T, Integer> counts;

    public DualPriorityQueue(int size, Comparator<T> c1, Comparator<T> c2) {
        queue1 = new PriorityQueue(size, c1);
        queue2 = new PriorityQueue(size, c2);
        counts = new HashMap<T, Integer>(size);
    }

    public T poll1() {
        return poll(queue1);
    }

    public T poll2() {
        return poll(queue2);
    }

    private T poll(Queue<T> queue) {
        T t = null;
        while (!queue.isEmpty() && !removeCount(t = queue.poll())) {
            t = null;
        }
        return t;
    }

    public boolean offer(T t) {
        queue1.offer(t);
        queue2.offer(t);
        addCount(t);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean removeCount(T t) {
        final Integer value = counts.get(t);
        if (value != null && value > 0) {
            final int newValue = value - 1;
            if (newValue == 0) {
                counts.remove(t);
            } else {
                counts.put(t, newValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void addCount(T t) {
        final Integer prev = counts.get(t);
        if (prev == null || prev <= 0) {
            counts.put(t, 1);
        } else {
            counts.put(t, prev + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The counting is needless complicated, you only need a `Set`. I actually implemented your solution (not exactly and not completely, a lot of tests are missing). See the links below another answer if interested. The remaining problem is the possible accumulation of invalid entries.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, if your queues are relatively small, using two priority queues is fine (I am not sure I understand the need for the marking). The reason you want to keep your queues small with `PriorityQueue` is that removal is O(n) not O(log n). This implementation of `poll()` has O(n log n) worst case, which makes its average case performance difficult to analyze.

Comment: Both of you are incorrect. A set would not account for multiple instances of the aame object properly. Because a priority queue can have two of the same object, that is necessary. Additionally, the amoritized performance is not difficult to calculate. Although the worst case of one poll could be nlogn, the average case performance over the entire time the structure is in use is log n. Because each element is only added and remove once from each priority queue, the overall performance is log n.

Comment: @Strikeskids: Perhaps amortized over the whole data structure usage, you may be right about the average performance. However, if the usage is mostly tilted towards one queue, then it can happen that usage of the other queue can always generate O(n log n) behavior. More worrisome is that a tilted use case can cause the rarely used queue to use unbounded memory.

Comment: @jxh the whole point of the algorithmic runtime estimation is to estimate over the entire queue. If you are so worried about the size of the other queue building up, then you can purge the elements that don't exist in the offending queue when it reaches double the total size of the double-queue. Even if one execution of the poll method takes significantly longer than the others, the overall execution time of the poll will be log n

Comment: @Strikeskids: The purge operation will also be O(n log n). I am just noting that this solution is not guaranteed to provide a "uniform" latency experience for all calls to `poll`. Perhaps you don't care about predictable latency, but there may be those that do.

Comment: @jxh evidently if you desire predictable latency, then this is not the implementation for you. Usually, the desire is to have the overall algorithm run efficiently, and this will provide the functionality in that use case.

Comment: @Strikeskids: I grant for the stated application (branch-bound optimization), this solution is likely sufficient, assuming the decision making is not tied to a real-time interface.

Answer (score 3):

Use two `TreeSet`s. Each set takes their respected comparator, and the `add()` method adds the provided value to each set. `poll1()` would acquire the `first()` value in the first set, and remove the value from both sets. Similarly for `poll2()`.

`add()`, `poll1()` and `poll2()` will have Ο(log *n*).

An example implementation follows (the real thing probably needs more error checking and additional methods):

```
class Priority2Queue <E>
{
    private TreeSet<E> q1;
    private TreeSet<E> q2;

    public Priority2Queue (Comparator<E> c1, Comparator<E> c2) {
        q1 = new TreeSet<E>(c1);
        q2 = new TreeSet<E>(c2);
    }

    public void add (E e) {
        q1.add(e);
        q2.add(e);
    }

    private E pollx (TreeSet<E> a, TreeSet<E> b) {
        E top = a.first();
        a.remove(top);
        b.remove(top);
        return top;
    }

    public E poll1 () { return pollx(q1, q2); }
    public E poll2 () { return pollx(q2, q1); }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is simple and sure to work, but pretty wasteful as a `TreeSet` takes much more memory and probably also time than a heap.

Comment: @maaartinus: I picked a data structure that would provide the correct big-O behavior. If your queue sizes are relatively small, two priority queues are probably sufficient. If you expect your queues to be very large, consider using a B+Tree implementation instead of `TreeSet`.

Comment: Surprisingly, your solution is way faster than my attempt to kajacx's answer. See my comments below his answer for links, if interested.

Comment: I see now, I've implemented something else... using two `PriorityQueue`s and keeping track of removals. I'll try your solution, too, one day.

Answer (score 2):

Use two priority queues.

One way to do this is tag an item for deletion when it's next in one's poll. If the other queue sees it, skip and move to next. I'm not sure the complexity of this, but it will depend on subtle questions such as how much longer one item remains in a queue than the other. I would suggest profiling for your actual situation.

Comment: +1 This is good, except for one thing, namely possible accumulation of already consumed things in one of the queues (as you noted). It may work well and profiling is no bad idea, but it can't tell me what happens for other inputs.

Answer (score 2):

If you care only about asymptotic complexity, i would go with @jxh's solution, which uses `O(n)` memory and guaranteed time `O(log(n))` per operation (that is the best possible) and requires very little coding.

However [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is backed by [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and that uses [`TreeEntry`](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML-release/javadocs/java/util/TreeMap.Entry.html) for entries, and one entry will take total `32B` of memory, plus having 2 trees will result into `64B` of memory per element!

**EDIT 2:** The old answer was incorrect, I have moved it [here](http://pastebin.com/Gg3Qmr2i) if anyone wants to see it anyway. Follows (hopefully) correct answer.

The idea is really simple. Let's have 2 ordinary heaps, one sorted via the first comparator, the other one sorted via the second comparator. And with that 2 indexing arrays that will link the elements between the heaps.

For example if element X is in position 2 in heap 1 and in position 8 in heap 2, then the linking arrays will look like this:

```
linkFrom1To2[2] = 8;
linkFrom2To1[8] = 2;
```

So if you perform any element moving in either of the heaps, you have to update these arrays accordingly.

But now if you remove minimum from one heap, you know where that element was in the second heap, so you can remove it from there as well.

I have posted the full code [here](http://pastebin.com/XAdJSgH4), this solution requires only `16B` per element and was even faster that the @jxh's solution in the tests I've done, but I used simple arrays with maximal capacity instead of some auto-growing structures like `ArrayList`.

Comment: Could you post your code? AFAIK the idea is similar to [MinMaxPriorityQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html), so I wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, look at at the code [here](http://pastebin.com/HC3Y3qdj), but it's not much cleaned-up, however you should see first inspection fail at epoch 19. The `add()` method doesn't work, because I forgot that when element changes floors, it's comparator towards lower elements also might change.

Comment: +1 purely for having the guts to put together your own code using well-known concepts.

Comment: I guess the problem is the order of steps 1 and 2 in `add`. By swapping with the grandparent you may introduce an inconsistency with the parent which never gets fixed. I [tried the other way round](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/TwofoldPriorityQueue.java) and so far the [test](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/TwofoldPriorityQueueTest.java) seems to pass. ([interface](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/ITwofoldPriorityQueue.java))

Comment: I was wrong, swapping the order doesn't suffice, the `selftest` was badly broken. I'm afraid that after a swap, more things have to be check and possibly fixed.

Comment: I've got it working, but have to look at grandparent, parent, both children, and all grandchildren in each step. Currently, it's [dead slow](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/ff079c65-4763-46db-9ff2-be68c192bb0f) as my [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/TwofoldPriorityQueueBenchmark.java) shows. [jxh's solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/SimpleTwofoldPriorityQueue.java) is way faster, but I like your idea more.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something akin to this.

```
public final class MyPriorityQueue < T >
{
  private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

  private final Queue < T > q1;
  private final Queue < T > q2;
  private final List < Queue < T > > queues;

  public MyPriorityQueue ( Comparator < T > comparator1,
      Comparator < T > comparator2 )
  {
    q1 = new PriorityQueue < T > ( INITIAL_CAPACITY, comparator1 );
    q2 = new PriorityQueue < T > ( INITIAL_CAPACITY, comparator2 );
    queues = Arrays.asList ( q1, q2 );
  }

  public void enqueue ( T t )
  {
    for ( Queue < T > queue : queues )
      queue.add ( t );
  }

  public T poll1 ()
  {
    T returnValue = q1.poll ();
    q2.remove ( returnValue );
    return returnValue;
  }

  public T poll2 ()
  {
    T returnValue = q2.poll ();
    q1.remove ( returnValue );
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

One other modification might be this.

```
public final class MyPriorityQueue < T >
{
  private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

  private final Map < Comparator < T >, Queue < T > > queues;

  public MyPriorityQueue ( List < Comparator < T > > comparators )
  {
    queues = new HashMap < Comparator < T >, Queue < T > > ();
    for ( Comparator < T > comparator : comparators )
    {
      Queue < T > q = new PriorityQueue < T > ( INITIAL_CAPACITY, comparator );
      queues.put ( comparator, q );
    }
  }

  public void enqueue ( T t )
  {
    for ( Queue < T > queue : queues.values () )
      queue.add ( t );
  }

  public T poll ( Comparator < T > comparator )
  {
    Queue < T > q = queues.get ( comparator );
    if ( q == null )
      return null;
    T returnValue = q.poll ();
    for ( Queue < T > queue : queues.values () )
      if ( queue != q )
        queue.remove ( returnValue );
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh god, i love spaces but why so much guy?

Comment: lolz, just the style I got used too. Most of my college friends hated it.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I guess because of spaces being cheap to print as they costs no ink? However, seeing so many them makes me eyes cry. The other problem is that `poll1` keeps the element in `q2`, which means I'd process it twice.

Comment: Updated to take into account removal from other queues

Comment: My intra-brain-parser parser keeps complaining about "uncomparable types" when reading `Queue < T` :-(